# Symfony 3.4 Test Failing With PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: But No Message

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4, php-7.1

I have a large suite of tests in Symfony that are run using simple-phpunit (I have Symfony's phpunit-bridge installed).

These tests were all passing until today.

Today I have two failed tests, both of which throw a "PHPUnit\Framework\Exception" followed by no message, but instead an object containing the actual test settings etc.

Here is what I see in the console (formatted here for legibility):

```
 1) Tests\ MyBundle\ Controller\ MyControllerTest::testMyController
PHPUnit\ Framework\ Exception: a: 4:
{
    s: 10: "testResult";N;
    s: 13: "numAssertions";i: 21;
    s: 6: "result";O: 28: "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult": 32:
    {
        s: 9: "*passed";a: 1:
        {
            s: 67: "Tests\MyBundle\Controller\MyControllerTest::testMyController";a: 2:
            {
                s: 6: "result";N;s: 4: "size";i: -1;
            }
        }
        s: 9: "*errors";a: 0:{}
        s: 11: "*failures";a: 0:{}
        s: 11: "*warnings";a: 0:{}
        s: 17: "*notImplemented";a: 0:{}
        s: 8: "*risky";a: 0:{}
        s: 10: "*skipped";a: 0:{}
        s: 12: "*listeners";a: 0:{}
        s: 11: "*runTests";i: 1;
        s: 7: "*time";d: 13.082627058029175;
        s: 15: "*topTestSuite";N;
        s: 15: "*codeCoverage";N;
        s: 28: "*convertErrorsToExceptions";b: 1;
        s: 7: "*stop";b: 0;
        s: 14: "*stopOnError";b: 0;
        s: 16: "*stopOnFailure";b: 0;
        s: 16: "*stopOnWarning";b: 0;
        s: 42: "*beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything";b: 1;
        s: 33: "*beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests";b: 0;
        s: 34: "*beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests";b: 0;
        s: 45: "*beStrictAboutResourceUsageDuringSmallTests";b: 0;
        s: 19: "*enforceTimeLimit";b: 0;
        s: 23: "*timeoutForSmallTests";i: 1;
        s: 24: "*timeoutForMediumTests";i: 10;
        s: 23: "*timeoutForLargeTests";i: 60;
        s: 14: "*stopOnRisky";b: 0;
        s: 19: "*stopOnIncomplete";b: 0;
        s: 16: "*stopOnSkipped";b: 0;
        s: 17: "*lastTestFailed";b: 0;
        s: 46: "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResultdefaultTimeLimit";i: 0;
        s: 42: "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResultstopOnDefect";b: 0;
        s: 77: "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResultregisterMockObjectsFromTestArgumentsRecursively";b: 0;
    }
    s: 6: "output";s: 0: "";
}
```

The only thing that has changed on this server is I had installed php7.1 but have now installed php7.1-dev.

Inside the suite of tests that throws this error, there are approximately five or so tests.  The weirdest thing is I can comment out my choice of any one test, and suddenly they all pass.  I can comment out the first one, leave the rest, and pass!  I can comment out only the last test, and then pass!  No one test appears to be the culprit here.

I have already configured PHP, both in php.ini, and in the phpunit.xml file to display all errors.

Does anyone know how I can get this to show a useful error?

And does anyone know why it is showing me all of the weird object stuff that displays the test results and settings etc. instead?

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `var_export` instead of serializing the error. It's quite ugly, and borderline unreadable.

Comment: That's the thing, I am not serializing the error.  This is what PHPUnit is choosing to show me.  For all other errors, it displays them properly on the console... but this one does this instead, and I don't know why.